# Scrape a part of website and notify on change

Tags: scripting, automation, web-scraping

The website of my university unfortunately does not provide feeds but they keep publishing information there that is important for me (deadlines,  dates of exams etc.) as links to pdfs
in a certain section of the website.

How can I regularly scrape that section of the site and have me notified (growl, mail something alike).

Normally I would use wget to mirror it but how to extract only parts of the website?
Is there a cli tool that can extract the XHTML via XPATH or similar?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
wget --spider --server-response http://example.com
```

This will print the headers which might contain the "Length"-attribute. If it changes, you can notify yourself.

**edit**: If it changes, you can download the whole html file, grep for a pdf file or whatever you want to look for (maybe for "<div id='news'>(.*?)</div>")

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... You should take a look at QueryPath. QueryPath makes easy to parse HTML. What if the HTML structure changes? What if you want specific elements of the page? QueryPath does the hard work for you. Do you like JQuery? QueryPath is like the JQuery of PHP.

See: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-querypath/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX01&S_CMP=HP
See: http://querypath.org/

Comment: Thanks Beto. No problem with JQuery. Unfortunately PHP is the one scripting language I am least keen on learning ;-)

Comment: You are welcome er4z0r. QueryPath was an interesting option :S

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking at [Pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) (disclaimer: this is my project). It's a web-scraping tool built on PhantomJS, giving you full jQuery access to the page in a headless Webkit browser context. It makes it very easy to pull semi-structured data from webpages via the command line, particularly if the page you're scraping has a consistent structure for new elements.

For example, you can pull all the course titles from [this course catalog](http://www.ischool.berkeley.edu/courses/catalog) with the following code:

```
pjs.addScraper(
    // the page you're scraping
    'http://www.ischool.berkeley.edu/courses/catalog', 
    // selector for elements you want to pull text from
    '.views-row .views-field-title'
);

// suppress STDOUT logging
pjs.config('log', 'none');
```

Running this from the command line gives you JSON to STDOUT by default:

```
~> phantomjs /path/to/pjscrape.js my_script.js
["W10. Introduction to Information","24. Freshman Seminar", ...]
```

So it would be pretty simple to run this script on a regular basis, capture the output in a file, and then alert you when the new output doesn't match the previous scrape. You can also write your own scraper functions, so there's a lot of flexibility for more complex scraping if a simple selector won't do the trick.